# Не могу победить java.lang.OutOfMemoryException: java heap space

Tags: java, outofmemoryerror

Помогите с советом, как победить java.lang.OutOfMemoryException: java heap space.

ОЗУ на ПК 8ГБ, и делал настройки -Xms7G, никак не проходить. Главное на МасBook при 8ГБ норм работает.

Суть такова, что загружаю с формы xlsx около 9000 строк, валится как раз на методе XSSFSheet.read. Если в этом файле оставить строк 5, то все ок.

сам метод загрузки создает объект каждой строки.

```
            rateClass = new RateClass(разные параметры, около 10 штук);
            if (!mapOfRates.containsValue(rateClass)) {
                mapOfRates.put(i, rateClass);
                i++;
            }
            rateClass = null;
```

Может кто-то сможешь подсказать, почему так(( На более мощной машине, где 16Гб озу и core i7 все нормально работает.

```
@Service
@Component
public class GetListOfRatesImpl implements GetList {
// Подключаем логгер
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetListOfRatesImpl.class);

// Основаная мапа, куда записываем все маршруты
private Map<Integer, RateClass> mapOfRates = new HashMap<>();

// Переменные для работы с файлами
private File file;
private FileInputStream fileInputStream;

// Переменные для работы с Excel файлом(формат XLSX)
private XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook;
private XSSFSheet sheet;
RateClass rateClass = null;

private GetListOfRatesImpl() {
}

@Override
public void fillMap() {
    mapOfRates.clear();
    // Получаем файл формата xls
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(this.file);
        xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

        // Заполняем Map данными
        sheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; j++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);

            String nameOfStationDeparture = null;
            String nameOfStationDestination = null;
            String customer = null;
            double rate = 0.00d;
            Date dateLoading = null;
            String nameCargo = null;
            String keyCargo = null;

            for (int c = 0; c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
                if (row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_NAME_STATION_DEPARTURE)) {
                    XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);
                    nameOfStationDeparture = xssfRow.getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
                }
                if (row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_NAME_STATION_DESTINATION)) {
                    XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);
                    nameOfStationDestination = xssfRow.getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
                }
                if (row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_CUSTOMER)) {
                    XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);
                    customer = xssfRow.getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
                }
                if (row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_NAME_CARGO)) {
                    XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);
                    nameCargo = xssfRow.getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
                }
                if (row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_KEY_CARGO)) {
                    XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);
                    if (xssfRow.getCell(c).getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.NUMERIC)) {
                        String val = Double.toString(xssfRow.getCell(c).getNumericCellValue());
                        double valueDouble = xssfRow.getCell(c).getNumericCellValue();
                        if ((valueDouble - (int) valueDouble) * 1000 == 0) {
                            val = (int) valueDouble + "";
                        }
                        keyCargo = val;
                    } else {
                        keyCargo = xssfRow.getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
                    }
                }
                if (row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_RATE)) {
                    XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);
                    rate = xssfRow.getCell(c).getNumericCellValue();
                }
                if (row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_DATE_LOADING)) {
                    XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);
                    dateLoading = xssfRow.getCell(c).getDateCellValue();
                    dateLoading.setHours(0);
                    dateLoading.setMinutes(0);
                    dateLoading.setSeconds(0);
                    if (dateLoading == null) dateLoading = new Date();
                }
            }
            rateClass = new RateClass(nameOfStationDeparture, nameOfStationDestination, customer, nameCargo, keyCargo, rate, dateLoading);
            if (!mapOfRates.containsValue(rateClass)) {
                mapOfRates.put(i, rateClass);
                i++;
            }
            rateClass = null;
        }
        logger.debug("Body rates: {}", mapOfRates);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Ошибка загруки файла - {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException e1) {
        logger.error("Некорректный формат файла заявок, необходим формат xlsx");
    }
}

public Map<Integer, RateClass> getMapOfRates() {
    return mapOfRates;
}

public void setMapOfRates(Map<Integer, RateClass> mapOfRates) {
    this.mapOfRates = mapOfRates;
}

public void setFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
    fillMap();
}
}
```

RateClass

```
public class RateClass implements Comparable<RateClass> {
// Подключаем логгер
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Route.class);

private String nameOfStationDeparture; // Станция отправления
private String nameOfStationDestination; // Станция назначения
private String customer; // Заказчик
private CargoClass cargo; // Груз
private double rate; // Ставка
private Date loadingDate; // Дата погрузки

public RateClass(String nameOfStationDeparture, String nameOfStationDestination, String customer, String nameCargo, String keyCargo, double rate, Date loadingDate) {
    this.nameOfStationDeparture = nameOfStationDeparture;
    this.nameOfStationDestination = nameOfStationDestination;
    this.customer = customer;
    this.cargo = new CargoClass(nameCargo, keyCargo);
    this.rate = rate;
    this.loadingDate = loadingDate;
}

public String getNameOfStationDeparture() {
    return nameOfStationDeparture;
}

public void setNameOfStationDeparture(String nameOfStationDeparture) {
    this.nameOfStationDeparture = nameOfStationDeparture;
}

public String getNameOfStationDestination() {
    return nameOfStationDestination;
}

public void setNameOfStationDestination(String nameOfStationDestination) {
    this.nameOfStationDestination = nameOfStationDestination;
}

public String getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(String customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public CargoClass getCargo() {
    return cargo;
}

public void setCargo(CargoClass cargo) {
    this.cargo = cargo;
}

public double getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(double rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public Date getLoadingDate() {
    return loadingDate;
}

public void setLoadingDate(Date loadingDate) {
    this.loadingDate = loadingDate;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    RateClass rateClass = (RateClass) o;
    return Double.compare(rateClass.rate, rate) == 0 &&
            Objects.equals(nameOfStationDeparture, rateClass.nameOfStationDeparture) &&
            Objects.equals(nameOfStationDestination, rateClass.nameOfStationDestination) &&
            Objects.equals(customer, rateClass.customer) &&
            Objects.equals(cargo, rateClass.cargo) &&
            Objects.equals(loadingDate, rateClass.loadingDate);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(nameOfStationDeparture, nameOfStationDestination, customer, cargo, rate, loadingDate);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RateClass{" +
            "nameOfStationDeparture='" + nameOfStationDeparture + '\'' +
            ", nameOfStationDestination='" + nameOfStationDestination + '\'' +
            ", customer='" + customer + '\'' +
            ", cargo=" + cargo +
            ", rate=" + rate +
            ", loadingDate=" + loadingDate +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int compareTo(RateClass o) {
    return o.loadingDate.compareTo(this.loadingDate);
}
}
```

Стек ошибки

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createChunk(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createNode(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createDeferredAttribute(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.setDeferredAttribute(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.readDocument(DocumentHelper.java:140)
org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:163)
org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:226)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:218)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:443)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:408)
org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:169)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:300)
com.uraltranscom.dynamicdistributionpark.service.impl.GetListOfRatesImpl.fillMap(GetListOfRatesImpl.java:72)
com.uraltranscom.dynamicdistributionpark.service.impl.GetListOfRatesImpl.setFile(GetListOfRatesImpl.java:158)
com.uraltranscom.dynamicdistributionpark.controller.Controller.routeList(Controller.java:51)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Приложите весь код, тут явно нет утечки, кроме как если Вы не переопределили equals в RateClass, то смысл проверки на совпадение?

Comment: OutOfMemory обычно происходит из-за неконтролируемой(бесконечной) рекурсии. У вас в коде нигде рекурсии нет? Если вы пишете в IntelliJ, то она помечает места с рекурсией специальным значком.

Comment: @GenCloud Код полностью приложил в классе и добавил код класса RateClass. ТАм я переобпеделял equals

Comment: @Anton238 Я то вроде не нуб, а тут все, тупик и не могу справится, причем мне именно на этой машине запустить надо приложение, а не могу)) Подстава прям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не могу уловить зачем используется `i`, может быть достаточно списка вместо `private Map<Integer, RateClass> mapOfRates = new HashMap<>();` или просто метод должен вернуть например: `public List<RateClass> getRateClass()` или `public Set<RateClass> getRateClass()` ?
2. Можно считывать сразу файл `XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);`
3. Можно удалить все поля в сервисе они особо не нужны
4. Кстати каждый `getRow` может создавать новый `Integer` если отличен от промежутка -128 - 127

   ```
   @Override
   public XSSFRow getRow(int rownum) {
       // Performance optimization: explicit boxing is slightly faster than auto-unboxing, though may use more memory
       final Integer rownumI = Integer.valueOf(rownum); // NOSONAR
       return _rows.get(rownumI);
   }
   ```

Вынести в переменную `XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);` выше цикла?

5. Вынести все переменные тем самым избежать создания лишних объектов например:

   import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
   import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Date;
   import java.util.List;

   @Service
   public class GetListOfRatesImpl implements GetList {

   ```
   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetListOfRatesImpl.class);

   @Override
   public List<RateClass> getRateClass(File file) {
       // Получаем файл формата xls
       List<RateClass> rateClasses = new ArrayList<>();
       try {

           XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

           XSSFSheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
           XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
           for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; j++) {
               XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.getRow(j);

               String nameOfStationDeparture = null;
               String nameOfStationDestination = null;
               String customer = null;
               double rate = 0.00d;
               Date dateLoading = null;
               String nameCargo = null;
               String keyCargo = null;

               for (int c = 0; c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
                   String headerCell = row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue().trim();
                   XSSFCell cell = xssfRow.getCell(c);

                   if (headerCell.equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_NAME_STATION_DEPARTURE)) {
                       nameOfStationDeparture = cell.getStringCellValue();
                   }
                   if (headerCell.equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_NAME_STATION_DESTINATION)) {
                       nameOfStationDestination = cell.getStringCellValue();
                   }
                   if (headerCell.equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_CUSTOMER)) {
                       customer = cell.getStringCellValue();
                   }
                   if (headerCell.equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_NAME_CARGO)) {
                       nameCargo = cell.getStringCellValue();
                   }
                   if (headerCell.equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_KEY_CARGO)) {
                       if (cell.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.NUMERIC)) {
                           Double numericCellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                           keyCargo = numericCellValue.intValue() + "";
                       } else {
                           keyCargo = cell.getStringCellValue();
                       }
                   }
                   if (headerCell.equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_RATE)) {
                       rate = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                   }
                   if (headerCell.equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_DATE_LOADING)) {
                       dateLoading = cell.getDateCellValue();
                       dateLoading.setHours(0);
                       dateLoading.setMinutes(0);
                       dateLoading.setSeconds(0);
                       if (dateLoading == null) dateLoading = new Date();
                   }
               }
               rateClasses.add(new RateClass(nameOfStationDeparture, nameOfStationDestination, customer, nameCargo, keyCargo, rate, dateLoading);)
           }
       } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
           logger.error("Ошибка загруки файла - {}", e.getMessage());
       } catch (OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException e1) {
           logger.error("Некорректный формат файла заявок, необходим формат xlsx");
       }
       logger.debug("Body rates: {}", rateClasses);
       return rateClasses;
   }
   ```

   }
6. keyCargo как то сложно? два раза `cell.getNumericCellValue()`

   ```
       if (headerCell.equals(JavaHelperBase.RATE_KEY_CARGO)) {
                   if (cell.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.NUMERIC)) {
                       Double numericCellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                       keyCargo = numericCellValue.intValue() + "";
                   } else {
                       keyCargo = cell.getStringCellValue();
                   }
               }
   ```

Кстати если хип дамп есть то в нем должно быть понятно каких объектов много и на чем можно сэкономить

Comment: Решение хорошее, я пробовал так тоже, все равно валится (( По поводу карты, она мне нужна дальше, именно нумерация ключей, то есть список мне не подходит. Дампа нет, точнее немею его снимать, читаю как снять

Comment: спасибо за предложения и советы. По поводу getCargo, сделал как вы написали

Answer (score 0):

Причину нашел, оказалась проблема на машине, переустановил JVM и все заработало, спасибо всем.